# How to avoid command bound to 'C' triggering on 'Ctrl-C'?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a GUI application in Python using Tkinter. I have a keyboard binding as follows:

```
tk.bind('<c>', lambda e: pressC())
tk.bind('<C>', lambda e: pressC())
```

If the user selects some text and attempts to copy it to the clipboard, the above binding is triggered. How do I avoid this behavior?

Comment: The way you are binding suppresses the event given as an argument. Bind to a function that accepts one argument and you will find additional information in that argument.

Comment: Okay, so how do I access that information once I change my function to take in the event as an argument?